# Request for Last 30 Days Top Users ladder

Tags: feature-request, reputation, statistics

<strike>Can we have an option to list users by their daily average reputation gain? It should just be a simple `totalReputation / numOfDaysAsMember`.</strike>

---

As a sub-request, can we get the exact number of days that someone is a member? I don't mind computing this metric myself, but something like "1 year" is way too inaccurate.

---

Thanks to the feedback so far (and so awesome of balpha to compute a snapshot), but here's a better idea:

If the rep/day metric is deemed too radically different from the rest of the metrics already implemented, then how about this: you know how tag-specific stats have both "all time" and "last 30 days" ladders? Well, the Users ladder right now is basically only "all time". If we can just have a "last 30 days" Users ladder, then it'd be *even better* than my original suggestion.

It measures exactly what it says: who in the last 30 days gained the most reps. It opens up one more avenue of competition, which will require more participation on a daily/monthly basis, which again is good for the community (e.g. currently, a top-ranked user can go on a month's vacation and probably wouldn't lose his/her spot in the "all time" ladder, but his/her standing in the "last 30 days" ladder could be compromised!).

Comment: I think it would encourage competition on a DAILY BASIS which I think would be good for the community. You can't slack off even for a single day because your average would drop. And to bring the average up, you may have to do more beyond the cap by pursuing bounties and acceptances, etc, which I think can be good.

Comment: Hover over the "Member for" section and you'll see their join date. Use that. [ed: this is for the sub-request, which really should be splintered off and closed as dupe]

Comment: @random - There's something to be said for decaying the rate more quickly than that so you can see their average *recent* rep gain.  Otherwise, for instance, one might think I'm highly active, when I haven't contributed much for about a year now, simply because I've got a high rep already.  That appears to be the goal here, anyway, given the emphasis on "encouraging competition on a daily basis".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with the others in disagreeing with your request, but you made me curious after all, so here's the first page of users with your sorting (as of April 1st):

1. <sub><sub>[image: Jon Skeet]</sub></sub> [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656): **297.31** rep/day (163963 rep, 551 days)
2. <sub><sub>[image: Alex Martelli]</sub></sub> [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810): **267.74** rep/day (91276 rep, 340 days)
3. <sub><sub>[image: Marc Gravell]</sub></sub> [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354): **243.24** rep/day (133482 rep, 548 days)
4. <sub><sub>[image: Pekka]</sub></sub> [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606): **190.44** rep/day (32863 rep, 172 days)
5. <sub><sub>[image: Pascal MARTIN]</sub></sub> [Pascal MARTIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138475): **189.81** rep/day (49314 rep, 259 days)
6. <sub><sub>[image: Bozho]</sub></sub> [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907): **188.80** rep/day (27610 rep, 146 days)
7. <sub><sub>[image: KennyTM]</sub></sub> [KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671): **188.20** rep/day (22122 rep, 117 days)
8. <sub><sub>[image: cletus]</sub></sub> [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393): **182.49** rep/day (102006 rep, 558 days)
9. <sub><sub>[image: polygenelubricants]</sub></sub> [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101): **181.53** rep/day (7521 rep, 41 days)
10. <sub><sub>[image: tvanfosson]</sub></sub> [tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12950): **179.31** rep/day (100652 rep, 561 days)
11. <sub><sub>[image: Daniel Vassallo]</sub></sub> [Daniel Vassallo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222908): **175.95** rep/day (21017 rep, 119 days)
12. <sub><sub>[image: Reed Copsey]</sub></sub> [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358): **172.92** rep/day (71412 rep, 412 days)
13. <sub><sub>[image: BalusC]</sub></sub> [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882): **170.06** rep/day (38486 rep, 226 days)
14. <sub><sub>[image: JaredPar]</sub></sub> [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283): **168.19** rep/day (92344 rep, 549 days)
15. <sub><sub>[image: Mehrdad Afshari]</sub></sub> [Mehrdad Afshari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33708): **160.35** rep/day (82300 rep, 513 days)
16. <sub><sub>[image: Neil Butterworth]</sub></sub> [Neil Butterworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69307): **159.68** rep/day (64425 rep, 403 days)
17. <sub><sub>[image: S.Lott]</sub></sub> [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661): **143.87** rep/day (80852 rep, 561 days)
18. <sub><sub>[image: Greg Hewgill]</sub></sub> [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893): **142.67** rep/day (85411 rep, 598 days)
19. <sub><sub>[image: Gumbo]</sub></sub> [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114): **140.36** rep/day (62750 rep, 447 days)
20. <sub><sub>[image: Péter Török]</sub></sub> [Péter Török](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265143): **138.00** rep/day (7810 rep, 56 days)
21. <sub><sub>[image: paxdiablo]</sub></sub> [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860): **137.33** rep/day (77023 rep, 560 days)
22. <sub><sub>[image: John Knoeller]</sub></sub> [John Knoeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234815): **132.27** rep/day (13643 rep, 103 days)
23. <sub><sub>[image: Andrey]</sub></sub> [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283676): **126.99** rep/day (3859 rep, 30 days)
24. <sub><sub>[image: VonC]</sub></sub> [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309): **126.47** rep/day (71335 rep, 564 days)
25. <sub><sub>[image: Johannes Schaub - litb]</sub></sub> [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509): **125.98** rep/day (64496 rep, 511 days)
26. <sub><sub>[image: Quassnoi]</sub></sub> [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159): **125.20** rep/day (55235 rep, 441 days)
27. <sub><sub>[image: Joel Coehoorn]</sub></sub> [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043): **123.65** rep/day (72017 rep, 582 days)
28. <sub><sub>[image: Jerry Coffin]</sub></sub> [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910): **123.17** rep/day (22789 rep, 185 days)
29. <sub><sub>[image: CMS]</sub></sub> [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445): **122.75** rep/day (69765 rep, 568 days)
30. <sub><sub>[image: henchman]</sub></sub> [henchman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284364): **121.07** rep/day (3572 rep, 29 days)
31. <sub><sub>[image: TomTom]</sub></sub> [TomTom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285465): **119.92** rep/day (3398 rep, 28 days)
32. <sub><sub>[image: Pascal Thivent]</sub></sub> [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604): **119.62** rep/day (47853 rep, 400 days)
33. <sub><sub>[image: Andrew Bezzub]</sub></sub> [Andrew Bezzub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289984): **118.37** rep/day (2620 rep, 22 days)
34. <sub><sub>[image: Kevin]</sub></sub> [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295112): **118.34** rep/day (1794 rep, 15 days)
35. <sub><sub>[image: Remus Rusanu]</sub></sub> [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929): **116.88** rep/day (37735 rep, 322 days)

<sub>(only counts users that had been active for at least two weeks)</sub>

Comment: @balpha would you share your script? I would like this as a regular feature on SO

Comment: @stacker: That's just a simple SQL query on the data dump.

Comment: Thank you for doing this! By the way, does anyone have any analysis on why the gap is so huge between 3rd (243.24) and 4th (190.44)? I find this anomaly fascinating.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Due to the daily reputation cap, you can only get 200 "regular" reputation points per day. That's (more or less) easily solved by posting lots of answers, each gaining just a single upvote. But to be over 200 per day (and consistently so), you need to regularly gain reputation through ways that are immune to the rep cap -- i.e. your answers have to be accepted. I'm not trying to imply that those people in the list that are below 200 post mediocre answers, but it's just a lot harder to jump from 190 rep/day to 210 than it is to go from 170 to 190.

Comment: In addition, there's no limit on the upvotes you can get on a particular answer, i.e. you can have a constant stream of "regular" reputation coming from that answer -- but it can only be accepted once, so the "over-the-cap" rep you can earn from the answer is bounded.

Comment: While everything balpha said is true I think the real reason is that most people stop posting for the day when they reach the cap.

Comment: Nice overview. But I was really not for 226 days active. I registered about 75 days before I posted for the first time (17 aug 2009 resp. 1 nov 2009). That would make it 255 rep/day.

Comment: @BalusC: Well, the OP asked for `totalReputation / numOfDaysAsMember` -- I guess you're out :-P

Comment: @balpha: Can we get an updated ladder for May =) Feel free to post this as your own "question" if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

The API provides enough information that one could make a utility to display this information, perhaps even using greasemonkey so it appears in place of the rep.

Comment: I also think a greasemonkey script will be enough.

Comment: The API doesn't make it possible to *sort* the users in this way -- you'd have to get all (!) users and do the calculation for each one of them. You're right, though, that getting this information for an individual user is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid thats not all people want that option, but you could check your daily rep gain on [this reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=276101&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true) by jon skeet

---

Regarding exact number of days being member, you just need to hover that "1 year" field in profile, it will show to exact time stamp

Answer (score 0):

What would be the (beneficial) practical use for this?  I think it would deter from the objectiveness of the sites when casting votes.  It shouldn't really matter how fast a user increases rep, so I don't really see a need to track the velocity.

It would show things like how fast someone is catching up to you or distancing themselves from you in earning rep and how active someone has been over the course of their stay, which you can just calculate from their profile.

Rep velocity can either indicate that someone is posting

- Lots of mediocre questions
- Lots of mediocre answers
- At least a few quality questions
- At least a few quality answers
- A mixture of the above

With the rep cap in place velocity is throttled which in turn skews the stat.

Comment: The number of votes reflects more popularity than quality. There are lots of quality answers with few votes because they're not popular.