# How to determine daily average reputation on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Hi,

How to determine daily average reputation on SO?

Comment: What would this be good for? The average is probably going to be close to zero, since there are hundreds of thousands of users who have only posted once.  It would be more useful to look at the distribution curve of rep earned over one day, to look at the median, standard deviation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-made function for this, but it seems to be a simple query on the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/creative-commons-data-dump-may-10/). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46997/request-for-last-30-days-top-users-ladder) for more detailed info.

Alternatively, you can analyze your reputation stats:

```
www.stackoverflow.com/reputation
```

Comment: The data dump link is 404ing