# Where can I find my personal stats for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics

I know you can search for "PHP" and select stats tab to show a list of the total number of votes next to the total number of answers/questions.

How can I view my own personal stats for tags such as PHP? Among many other tags?

Comment: Check out the second query in [this question's body](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/) for upvotes, at least

Comment: @ccomet, thanks for pointing this out, it's exactly what I had needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great greasemonkey script which shows that in your profile page.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations/22856#22856

[image]