# Style visited links differently on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

[SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is becoming a more and more useful tool all the time as people are writing [interesting queries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) and sharing them here on meta.  A few of these have brought up some issues that could use a little clean-up.  It would be helpful if the visited links in the results had a different style so I can see where I've been when I return to the Data Explorer window.  Thanks.

[Here's an example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1165) so you can the results listing.

Comment: totally, waffles is on the case :)

Comment: @waffles: Much better.  That will save me some eyestrain.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They should cornify them.