# How can I determine the number of votes earned in a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

How can I determine the number of votes earned in a particular tag for SO?

**Edit:**

This query showed the same result which i had checked about 20 days ago:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1928

It looks like it is not real time, rather a dump as said by @S. Mark in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not real time, but based on datadump

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1928

ref: [Interesting queries on Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer)

Comment: so there is no real time? in the link you posted, it showed the same number of votes when i had checked about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: You know, stackoverflow data dump is available every month. So its not that too old.

Comment: @S.Mark: hmm, thanks for your answer i did not know they do it monthly. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz, for data dump, I would refer to blog posts here - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Answer (score 1):

There's been a change.

If you go to the tag page e.g. [`discussion`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=discussion&sort=info&pagesize=50) here on meta and click on the "info" tab you'll see how many up-votes you've received in non-community wiki posts.

> You were upvoted 511 times on non community-wiki answers with this tag.

(which is what I see).

There doesn't seem to be a lower limit to the reputation needed to see this.

This is also realtime.