# Notify/contact SEDE user of fix to query

Tags: feature-request, comments, data-explorer

I guess I'm asking for comments, with subsequent notifications, to be added to queries in SEDE, so we can point out [fixes] [1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/2596) to flawed queries, especially when [the query] [0](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/2528) has a comment in it explaining the problem.

Comment: Does it make sense to simply ask the question on Stack Overflow? I did entertain the idea of making some sort of game where you ask a question and get an answer in sql upvoting the best answer, but its dangerously close to Stack Overflow area

Comment: @waffles Probably, especially if we can identify users on SEDE with users on Meta or SO, like I was able to here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer (see question comment where I notified BalusC).

Comment: @JonSeigel: Well in that case, the other question is the duplicate because it was a month later :-)

Comment: I chose the other as the master because Waffles responded to it. Oh well, as long as one of them is closed as a dupe of the other.