# Data Explorer needs the ability to comment on queries

Tags: feature-request, comments, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notify/contact SEDE user of fix to query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52887/notify-contact-sede-user-of-fix-to-query)

I just tried out odata.stackexchange.com for the first time - quite impressive!

However, I really missed the abilty to comment on other queries and have people comment on mine.

Any plans to add this?

Comment: The linked question doesn't have any answers, only comments. Should it be a reason to re-open this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm all for having comments if it's carefully designed.

Data Explorer is [open source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/stack-exchange-data-explorer-open-sourced/) and a patch that adds this kind of feature would be more than welcome.

I am totally swamped with bringing more awesome to the Stack engine at the moment, so I have not had too much time in the last few weeks to work on SEDE.

So to answer your question, there are plenty of plans I would love comments, graphs even possibly something like "gist" that you can embed into your site and code contributions would be more than welcome. What is lacking though is time :)

Answer (score -2):

Post your query as an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer), this will let people notice it, vote on it and add comments. There's a chance the query you want to discuss might be on there as well.

Comment: Ability to communicate about particular query is unrelated is query interesting or not