# Data Explorer - Invalid Query: Electorate Badge Progress

Tags: support, data-explorer, electorate-badge

The following data explorer query for Stackoverflow does not give expected results:

[Electorate Badge Progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/470/electorate-badge-progress)

User question and answer voting data is not available in public data dumps so the intent of the query cannot work. It is not possible to work out Electorate badge progress for a user.

The query actually reports on favourite question votes which is non-obvious and confusing. Perhaps the necessary data was dumped at some stage, but this query no longer makes sense.

**Can this invalid and confusing query be removed?**

I would like this query to be removed as:

1. It is incorrect.
2. Understanding the conditions for the Electorate badge is difficult enough without misleading queries.

Comment: Not an answer (which is why I'm using a comment) but you can now check Electorate progress directly at the `/review` page, which makes this query (and others like it) unnecessary.

Comment: Assuming one has the Strunk & White badge.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a touchy issue.

People are allowed to put in any query they like, so it's difficult to filter out the ones that don't work, or are out of date (for example, there are a bunch of queries that count the number of edits, but don't use the new PostHistory information).

There is a pending [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56513/data-explorer-needs-the-ability-to-comment-on-queries) to allow commenting on queries. Perhaps it would help if we could notify the author that a query isn't working properly, or at least notify everyone who is planning to run the query. I suppose the author could be contacted directly if they provide contact information in their profile.

In the meantime, however, I don't think that anything should be done.

What I would recommend is recreating the query yourself, making the appropriate corrections.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately as I have mentioned in my question there is no valid query for this situation - the exported data does not support it. Maybe we could have a facility to "close" queries as we do to close questions? I'll start a new post on exactly this actually.

Comment: @chibacity: Oh yeah, good point. Edited. Hmmm.. closing a query... that's a pretty good idea. It might help to clean up old/invalid/duplicate queries.