# Ability to "vote to close" Data Explorer queries

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, data-explorer

I have recently come across an SO Data Explorer query which produces incorrect results and posted a question about having it removed:

[Data Explorer - Invalid Query: Electorate Badge Progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77515/data-explorer-invalid-query-electorate-badge-progress)

This particular query is both incorrect, but also cannot be implemented correctly as it would rely on data that is not exported publicly i.e. user question voting data.

I propose the ability to "vote to close" queries so that queries can be cleaned up by the community where appropriate, much as questions can be closed on SO. Having the ability to "close" a query because it does not work seems sensible. The reasons for closing can serve to finesse the situation as it does on SO.

In the spirit of how closed questions are treated on SO, closed queries could be considered for deletion. This would allow certain queries that are not useful to be closed and then deleted i.e. cleaned up by the community.

Comment: Would closing a query do anything apart from adding a warning to the query that it's closed?

Comment: @Simon Initially yes, but it could also be reviewed\considered for deletion.