# Arithmetic overflow error on SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer

From the answer to my previous question, I found this Data Explorer query:

[StackOverflow Rank and Percentile](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile)

I put my `user_id` (897326) and click `Run`. I get this error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting bigint to data type numeric.
```

Comment: As Siva alludes to below these are user-defined queries and not related to Stack Exchange. If you have a problem with a query that you can't fix, consider asking on Stack Overflow (after first checking that there is no duplicate).

Comment: @Ben In the original version of the question Neolisk was asking whether MSO was the correct place to ask this, and I edited it out, thinking this _might_ have been an issue with SEDE and not the query itself.

Comment: I've corrected the query.  I didn't even know people were using it or that so many people had favorited it.  It obviously will fail for any user id > 99999.  I guess two years ago that didn't seem like such a big deal (and how many of the higher users would have any significant ranking...).

Comment: @CadeRoux: thanks for the update. It's amazing how good old things are still being used today. Many examples. :)

Comment: @Neolisk It _would_ be good if we got notifications from SEDE about things that need comments.

Comment: @CadeRoux: agree. You can vote on it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52887/notify-contact-sede-user-of-fix-to-query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fork the query by clicking `fork query` link and then change it according to your needs. In this case, I changed the type casting from `CAST(Ranking AS decimal(10, 5))` to `CAST(Ranking AS decimal(20, 5))` and the query ran fine for your user id.

#### Link to the updated query:

[StackOverflow Rank and Percentile](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/84262/97293/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile)

#### Note to the original author:

I have left a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198384/what-does-gt-0-mean-in-sql/13198490#comment18004775_13198490) on one of the SO posts by the original author [Cade Roux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18255/cade-roux).

Comment: Thanks - now it works. But it does not update the original query. So what about those who starred the original query, or various links to it from different part of SO?

Comment: @Neolisk: I have left a [comment about this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198384/what-does-gt-0-mean-in-sql/13198490#comment18004775_13198490) on one of the posts by the author.

Comment: Looks like pretty much decentralized, meaning you would have to find an author's post on something and comment on that, even if it's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: @Neolisk You may be interested in this feature request: [Notify/contact SEDE user of fix to query](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52887)

Comment: Thanks, @Tim - I upvoted and posted a related suggestion in there.