# How close am I to earning the <TagName> badge

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, tag-badges, bounties

I have a request for someone to write a query in the data explorer that will accurately predict how close someone is to earning a tag-based badge.

The current query ([How Many Upvotes Do I have for each tag](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag)) says that I have over 1000.

Or, if it cannot be done any better, please tell me why.

<sub>I would do this myself, but I am not experienced at SQL at all.</sub>

Comment: Looks like that query includes CW votes as well, which isn't counted for the badge.

Comment: That was my guess too.  However, in my quick attempts, I couldn't get it to exclude them. (@Kenny)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: This computes the score while tag badges are counted by upvotes only. [@BalusC's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53858/how-close-am-i-to-earning-the-tagname-badge/53862#53862) should be correct.

---

Try this query instead, which I forked from that calculates [Generalist badge](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/734/how-long-until-i-get-the-generalist-badge?edit=82):

- http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/3950/undefined

```
-- What is my score for each badge?
-- What is the net non-CW upvote for all tags I have participated?

declare @temp table (id int identity(1,1), TagName char(128), score int);

with answers as (
  select score, id, parentId from posts  -- find responses of questions
  where communityowneddate is null   -- which are non-comm-wiki
  and posttypeid = 2                 -- answers
  and owneruserid = ##UserId##       -- by you
)

insert @temp(TagName, score)
select t.TagName, sum(a.score) as score from answers a
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = a.parentId -- find tags of your answers
inner join tags t on pt.tagid = t.id
group by t.tagname
order by score desc

select *, case when score >= 1000 then 'S,G' when score >= 400 then 'S' else '' end from @temp
```

This shows you still need 47 votes to get a gold badge in [`[java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/44/java).

(Note that these rare badges may not be handed out immediately when you reach 1,000.)

Comment: This seems like it may be correct.

Comment: This one is probably right, because it's slightly low on java (-14), swing (-3), and generics (-1), and I think that's about how many upvotes I've gotten this month.

Comment: this calculates *score* for each tag - ie upvotes - downvotes, not just upvotes.  Is this what's counted for tag badges?  (I'm not sure...)

Comment: This seems to be what's calculated on the stats pages. I guess the question is whether that's the same as what's calculated for the badges.

Answer (score 2):

[The first query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1928) of [this overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) already takes CW votes into account.

Comment: That's what I just tried (checking the wiki date), but it's still wrong according to the stats pages. It's off by +25 on java, -1 on swing, and +1 on generics.

Comment: @mmyers: That's because the data are from May 31st, not today.

Comment: @Kenny, why would mmyers have more upvotes in the past than he does now?

Comment: This one says I have 995.  But, I have received more than 5 (or 6) java votes since I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/3948).  My SQL is a bit rusty, but I think it's OK.  I believe it only counts non-wiki posts, or votes before a post becomes wiki....

I've updated my query a bit - it breaks out

1. Upvotes on posts that have never been CW.
2. Upvotes on CW posts before they became CW (so I believe these should be counted)
3. Upvotes on CW posts after they became CW (definitely out)
4. Total upvotes (just for reference)

(1 + 2 + 3 == 4 unless I've done something crazy)

Comment: It shows the same (1073) for total votes, but it still shows 1050 for non CW votes. `:(`

Comment: The new query isn't showing me all of those results.  Did you change the link?