# Badge idea: Highlander - There Can Be Only One

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Give this badge for

- having `{some number of}` of the following:

  - a `{good enough answer}`,
  - to a `{fair competition question}`,
  - which have no competing answers

Some measures are :

- `{good enough answer}`: acceptance or upvotes or a combination thereof.
- `{fair competition question}`: age<sup>(see note)</sup> or number of views or a combination thereof.

Essentially we want to reward those who've provided non-garbage answers to questions which for one reason or another no one else bothered to answer. Maybe it's too hard, maybe it's too boring, maybe the topic/technology is too niche/obscure, maybe it's just a bad question not worth answering<sup>(see note)</sup>, maybe the question is already adequately answered and there's no point in providing an alternative, etc.

The question has to allow for fair competition. The emphasis is not in being *the first* to answer the question; it's about being *the only one* to answer the question, despite ample chance for others to provide alternative/competing answers.

---

*Notes*:

To clarify, it's not necessary to provide a new answer to an old unanswered question. The answer itself may just be as old as the question, so in that sense this is not a dupe of `{Necromancer}`.

Also, one reason that there may not be a competing answer is perhaps because it's such a bad question that no one else bothered to take the time. In that sense there's similarity with `{Reversal}`, but where as `{Reversal}` really rewards "good" answer to a "terrible" question, this badge rewards being *the only one* to answer a question, regardless of the quality of the question.

I'm going to guess that most scenarios that are eligible for `{Reversal}`, aren't eligible for this badge.

Comment: Perhaps at some point I'll attach a stexdex query result to show what kind of Q/A qualifies for the badge. I may do this over the weekend if I have the time/energy.

Comment: I think awarding should depend on if inductees successfully answer the following question: "Is there a sequel to 'The Highlander' movie"?

Comment: @OMG: Yes, but it took 2 movies to get to it.

Comment: I like this, but it does overlap a bit with "good answer" and "enlightened"

Comment: @waffles: Yes, non-garbage answers are already rewarded by a variety of badges, but this is different in that: (i) it requires `{some number of}` non-garbage answers (say, 10?) to earn just one. (ii) each user can only earn at most one (simplifies many things, and I think in line with other badges of this style).

Comment: @polygenelubricants, 10? Is this meant as silver or gold badge? To reward a long-running pattern, I proposed a [gold badge for the revival/necromancer pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268), **Persephone**.

Answer (score 8):

I've created [a data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8730/highlander-badge) for you.