# Request: Include the answer accepted date in the monthly data dump

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump

Is there any chance of including the "answer accepted date" in the Data Dump?  Specifically I mean when you hover over the accepted answer checkmark you get a tooltip:

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer xx units ago

Can we include that time property in the dump....or is it already there and I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *date* is already in there, but the *time* is not. (Not in Data Explorer anyways... it may be in the data dump itself, but I just deleted the last one and haven't downloaded the new one.)

Anyway, run this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId = 1
```

You can see the dates show up in the CreationDate column, but the times are all 12:00.

Upvotes and downvotes are anonymized by both stripping the source user id and the time, and I assume this was carried through to the accepted date. However, I don't think this makes sense, since the accepted times are publicly visible in the system.

I think I'd call this a bug, actually.

Comment: There goes my "Tuesday has the most accepted answers" theory: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/8934/ Thanks Jon, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @NickCraver Did you see my queries [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer/51695#51695)?

Comment: @Mark - Yup, I found those results interesting as well...in this case I was specifically after accepted answers, maybe you could add that column to your results to make those queries even more useful?

Comment: @NickCraver Done.