# Time of Accepted Answer in Stack Exchange Dump

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, data-dump

I was looking into the Stack Exchange dump and wanted to try to get more information on when an accepted answer is declared. The Votes table had been suggested in a [previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59503/request-include-the-answer-accepted-date-in-the-monthly-data-dump) since it has a type that marks when an answer is accepted (1 = "AcceptedByOriginator") but it does not give an exact time (defaults to midnight).

Since the last post was awhile ago, trying to confirm if there are any new elements I might have missed that can capture when the answer was accepted or if there is a related feature to the request in the previous post that I can check to see if it fulfills my needs.

Comment: Accepting an answer is a vote, and [vote timestamps are truncated to date by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933/295232).

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248526/158100