# Where is the frontend to the database for stackexchange-2.0 sites?

Tags: discussion, database, stack-exchange

At some point, a few days ago, I stumbled across a database frontend for the Stackexchange-2.0 sites. One could get various statistics and write general queries to the database. I've been looking for that site without much success....

Could someone direct me to such a page?

Is there a way to compare the different stackexchange-2.0 site using my own metrics? For example I would like to plot:

> Average time-lag for the answer that is eventually selected, to be posted.

I'm not asking that someone write the query for me, just tell me where I can try my hand at writing the query myself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new ?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I considered writing it like that and thought I'd make full use of the mighty power of hyperlinks (at the expense of readability). Next time I'll get my answer right the first time. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE) has the data your are looking for. All Stack Exchange sites have their databases exported to SEDE once per month, once they have graduated from the Beta phase. Data from sites in Beta are not available for download. Currently, cross-site queries are not supported; you must select which data set to run the query on.

Comment: The latter *is* possible, just slightly hacky: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/allow-cross-site-queries-in-data-explorer/83581#83581