# Data Explorer query to find answers of specific user based on a keyword

Tags: support, search, data-explorer, sql

I'm looking for SQL query to use within [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), to bring back all my answers (per site, from only one site at a time) with my userid and with a particular keyword, in the body of my answers.

I do not need to do this cross-site or SE communities.

Comment: Yes, MSE is the correct place to get support on [data.se] query. As for hint on cross-site query, read [Allow cross-site queries in data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/allow-cross-site-queries-in-data-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/431591/find-answers-of-specific-user-by-a-keyword):

```
Select Id As [Post Link], CreationDate
From Posts
Where PostTypeId=2 --Answers
    And OwnerUserId=##UserId##
    And Body Like '%##keyword##%'
Order By CreationDate Desc
```

[Sample search](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/431591/find-answers-of-specific-user-by-a-keyword?UserId=510662&keyword=performant).

Comment: I'm not sure why I struggled with that so hard and everything is in the same one table. I tried joining other tables, etc. and I couldn't get the results I expected and BAM, you know the query and it's all in the same one table... I totally overlooked trying to figure this out and I appreciate your answer! I think it may have been the OwnerUserId that confused me and thinking I had to get these results from joining to different tables. Thanks a lot for this answer!!

Comment: Sometimes we just over-complicate things, no worry  - it happened to me lots of times, @1Fish. Cheers!