# Please add a Privileges table to the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I was reviewing some of the ["Interesting queries on Data Explorer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/148310), and saw that the top-voted answer, ["How many users can do X?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54452/148310), was broken and obsolete.  *And*, it only had data for Stack Overflow proper -- not any of the dozens of other sites or their metas.

I set about to revive, update, and broaden this query and quickly ran up against some problems:

1. There is no table of *Privileges* in the SEDE data.  There *are* [tables of *Privileges* in the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges#filter=default&site=superuser&run=true), but that is not usable in SEDE.
2. Trying to hand-create a table of privileges, [like in this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/89582/), is not a good option, because of the need to constantly hand-check dozens of sites for changes. (Note that that query's table was based on just a sample of 6 sites and 6 metas.)
3. <strike>There is no way for a SEDE query to know what site's data it is operating on.  That means that queries that depend on site-specific data have no way of delivering accurate and *concise* results.  See [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/89582/), again, for example.</strike>

As Nick pointed out, `DB_NAME()` is set to match the source site.

So, **Please add a Privileges table** to the Data Explorer. Which would return site-specific reputation requirements, just like [the API][6] does.

Comment: For 1) why does our internal Site ID matter? Keep in mind you can already see where you are with `DB_NAME()`.  For 2) This isn't actually stored strictly in the DB, there are code components so it's not a copy/paste operation, but I can take a look when time allows.

Comment: @NickCraver, I didn't know that the database name would be set to match the site. (Did I miss some documentation?) Site ID doesn't matter, except that queries should be more efficient matching an integer rather than a string.  Anyway, thanks for the info, `DB_Name()`/`DB_ID()` should work just fine.  And, we can get a list of database names with `select name from sys.databases`.

Comment: The matching is a side-effect of how I do the import really, but they've always been close.  Privileges I don't disagree with but it's not a simple view...we want to re-work how privileges are stored in general, we'll probably get this *much* cleaner, then get them exported since the export would just have to change.  It'll have to wait a bit though...it's currently working so not high up in the to-do queue.

Comment: @NickCraver, understand the low priority.  Fully agree with rework before trying to export.  I'll probably use the API to semi-automate generating an all-sites `@PrivilegeRequirements` SQL, now that I know how to filter down to the current site in queries.