# Is there a way to search comments?

Tags: support, comments, search

The search on the top of the page searches questions and answers .

Is there a way to search comments too ?

Comment: You can also use this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273888/search-inside-comments-of-specific-user-now-case-insensitive

Comment: @ShadowWizard UserID refers to ?

Comment: Your user ID on the site you want to search your comments in. You don't have any associated accounts so can't see, but for example your ID here is 286453 as can be seen in the URL to your profile: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/286453/funny` - the number before the display name is the user ID.

Comment: Also keep in mind the data in the link I gave in my first comment (Data Explorer) is not live, and updated every Sunday or Monday only.

Comment: I want to search other user's comment . due to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251197/286453) . So the user's meta.SE 's userID must be added ?

Comment: Yes, you should select MSE and enter the user's ID, for example [searching for the word "fun" in the comments from the user you linked to](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/273888/search-inside-comments-of-specific-user-now-case-insensitive?userid=52443&text=fun).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks . Got it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there a way to search for the most upvoted comments of a SE site ?

Comment: If you mean list of comments sorted by score then sure, [simple SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/291153/most-upvoted-comments). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks . [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/286453) will help me understand SEDE better :)