# Useful Data Queries

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer, faq-proposed

Over on [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), we've come up with [a list of data queries](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2013/2685). [HDE226868 suggested](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/worldbuilding-data-queries/2014?noredirect=1#comment4534_2013) that these queries might be useful to other sites, and we should post them on Meta: this is the result.

This post is a re-list of all the queries we've come up with. It will be updated as new queries are invented, but you may wish to check both posts to get the full list.

As with the post on Worldbuilding, if you have a query you wish to add, just edit it in. **Please avoid making new answers for your queries**, I have seen query lists get incredibly messy because of this. The answer is community wiki, so most people can edit it.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate (is interesting ~ useful?); definitely related: [Interesting queries on Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/168244)

Comment: I'm wondering whether mods could/should merge these posts...

Comment: @Werner that's more about interest - we've tried to design these to be useful in moderating or monitoring the health of a site.

Comment: Can we pleaaaassseeee have this [tag:faq-proposed]? I think that this would be a great way to help redirect users to a single spot where they can find data about SE sites.

Comment: This does not strike me as a FAQ; it may be *useful* (and so the title claims) but I'm not seeing this as a frequently-asked-question. Let it be what it is...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Voting and Moderation

- [**Upvotes Over Time**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300882/upvotes-over-time) - shows how many votes each post received on average over time.
- [**Percentage of questions closed**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300940/percentage-of-questions-closed) - shows a simple rundown of total questions, closed questions, and the percentage of questions closed.

## Post Statistics

- [**Distribution of Votes on Answers**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300919/distribution-of-votes-on-answers#graph) - shows how many answers have how many votes. I find the graph most interesting here.
- [**Distribution of Votes on Questions**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300923/distribution-of-votes-on-questions#graph) - shows how many *questions* have how many votes. Again, the graph is very interesting.
- [**Asked/Closed/Reopened per week**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300932/asked-closed-reopened-per-week#graph) - shows the number of questions asked, closed and reopened together in a graph.
- [**Number of questions with respective number of answers**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300931/number-of-questions-with-respective-number-of-answers#graph) - shows the number of questions that has each specific number of answers. (For example, how many questions have 0 answers, 1 answer, 2 answers, ..., 10 answers, ...)

## Posts to Watch

- [**Possible low-quality answers**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300384/possible-downvote-worthy-answers) - gives a list of answers which satisfy some common criteria of low-quality answers. Note that being in this list does not automatically make an answer low quality, they should still be evaluated on their own merits.
- [**New Answers to Old Questions**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302141/new-answers-to-old-questions) - shows answers from the last week posted on questions more than 30 days older.
- [**Highest Voted Posts**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302101/highest-voted-posts) - gives the top 15 highest voted posts from the last week.
- [**Lowest Voted Posts**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302107/lowest-voted-posts) - gives the top 15 lowest voted posts from the last week.
- [**Most Commented**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302123/most-commented) - lists the 15 most commented posts of the last week.
- [**Most Viewed**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302126/most-viewed) - lists the 15 most viewed questions of the last week.
- [**Most Edited**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/302129/most-edited) - lists the 15 most edited posts of that were last edited in the last week.

## Users

- [**Distinct Contributors per week**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/171748/distinct-contributors-per-week#graph) - shows the number of *different* users engaged in different activities per week. Taken directly from [TWP](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2667/27355).
- [**New Users per week**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/161189/users-by-date-joined#graph) - shows the number of new users who joined each week. Again, from TWP.
- [**New User Progress**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300967/newuserprogress?daysSinceJoined=14) - shows newly-contributing users, showing numbers of questions/answers and rep.

## Tags

- [**Tag Usage over time**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=science-based#graph) - shows how much a tag has been used over time as a graph of number of posts against time.

## General Activity/Utility

- [**Site Activity and Voting graph**](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph) - a graph of significant stats like votes, questions and answers, all per week. Copied from TWP.

Comment: I really liked Possible low-quality answers

Comment: @Pushpak That stemmed out of worldbuilding having a downvoting problem...