# How many upvotes does Jon Skeet have?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, up-votes, fun

Since daily rep caps out at 200, a large majority of upvotes on Jon's posts never get "counted" as rep.

- For example, more than 70 upvotes on 11/17/17 did not count toward his rep total.

My question is: **how many *upvotes* does [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=profile) have?**

Motive: I am interested in examining user output/quality using a less penalizing approach than rep counts (which is limited/throttled).

- Specifically, I'm curious about who might have the most upvotes (vs rep), since those with daily high-rep don't get quantified equally to those that do not reach the daily max.

Update: This is not a dupe of [Interesting queries on Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) because my question is neither asked nor answered in that post.

- I want to know the *total* number of upvotes a user (in this case Jon) has *ever* received across all posts on a given SE site (Stack Overflow).

Comment: Have you looked into [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) yet?

Comment: no never heard of it. I'll look into it now...

Comment: @theforestecologist Then write the query.  Meta isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @Servy I'm actually currently trying to figure out how to do just that. I'll post an answer after I finish figuring it out

Comment: Would someone explain to me why this is getting so many downvotes????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the ["Top 10 Total All-Time UpVoted Users" Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/764238/946631/top-10-total-all-time-upvoted-users) that I created via the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/),
we can see Jon Skeet does *in fact* have the most upvotes of any user.

**As of 11/27/2017, Jon skeet has 378374 upvotes**

The top 10 most upvoted users are:

[image]

**2018 Update** (1 year later - 11/28/2018):

[image]

**2019 Update** (2 years later - 11/30/2019):

[image]

**2020 Update** (3 years later - 12/19/2020):

[image]

**2021 Update** (4 years later - 12/28/2021):

[image]

Comment: Yes, I taught myself sql and how to do this this afternoon. It's probably not the best query, but it gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is <s>42</s> [378374](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/764060/number-of-upvotes-for-a-certain-user?UserId=22656).

<sub>(As of 26 November 2017 morning; SEDE is updated once a week, and including Community Wiki posts. If you don't want those, feel free to write your own query; it's a nice exercise for your SEDE skills.)</sub>